# Javascript - scoping an incrementing-loop counter only to that loop

Tags: javascript

I've run into this error multiple times now, and wondering if there's a way to have the code auto control for it?

```
var length = some_array.length
for (var i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
  someMethod(some_array[i].name) 
}

function someMethod(name) {
  var length = other_array.length
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i ++ ) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

The code above doesn't run properly because the inner `i` and `length` carry over to the outer level code. So to actually make it work, I have to manually set different variables to manage the scoping. I.e., something like the below works:

```
var length = some_array.length
for (var i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
  someMethod(some_array[i].name) 
}

function someMethod(name) {
  var s_length = other_array.s_length
  for (var s_i = 0; s_i < length; s_i ++ ) {
    // some code
  }
}
```

But of course, it's hard to always remember when an inner function has another loop in it. Wondering if there's a way to control it so that loop variables are always only constrained to THAT loop itself.

Comment: Take a look at the `let` keyword.

Comment: `The code above doesn't run properly because the inner i and length carry over to the outer level` no, they don't - you must be doing something else wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is why `let` keyword is a better option than var- it keeps the scope to just the function or method that calls it.

The following snippet consoles -

```
0 / test 1 / 0 / test a
0 / test 1 / 1 / test b
1 / test 2 / 0 / test a
1 / test 2 / 1 / test b
```

ie: for each item of some_array - it calls someMethod and consoles the name of the first array as well as each iteration of the second array (other_array).

```js
let some_array=[{id: '1', name: 'test 1'},{id: '2', name: 'test 2'}];
let other_array=[{id: 'a', name: 'test a'},{id: 'b', name: 'test b'}];

let length = some_array.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
  someMethod(i, some_array[i].name) 
}

function someMethod(index, name) {
  let length = other_array.length
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i ++ ) {
    console.log(index + ' / ' + name + ' / ' + i + ' / ' + other_array[i].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the same output regardless of `let` or `var` here. Maybe there's a better example? `i` inside `someMethod` is scoped to the function.

Comment: Each i IS scoped to its location - I just amended it to log the i's as well and as you can see - each log shows its place in the sequence - 0/0 , 0,1 , 1,0 ,11 - or in other words - for each of the i's in the first gtopu its calling the method and in the method - its iteratnig over the second list.

Comment: So, maybe I'm just missing the point. What would be different if you replaced all the `let`s with `var`s?

Answer (score 0):

**SCOPE**

In JavaScript there are two types of scope:

Local scope
Global scope
JavaScript has function scope: Each function creates a new scope.

`let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block.
Notice how `var` create a property on the global object but `let` is undefined.

```
var x = 'global';
let y = 'global';
console.log(this.x); // "global"
console.log(this.y); // undefined
```

Let's try it with your code.

```
let some_array = [{ name: 'Angel' }, { name: 'James' }]
let other_array = ['0','1'];

//let i is declared local
for (let i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++) {
    someMethod(some_array[i].name) //"let" some_array variable is required here to the local "for loop" scope.
}

function someMethod(name) {
//let i is declared local here again so it's considered a new variable i.
    for (let i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++) {
        console.log(name)
    }
}
```

[For more examples about scope in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: Wouldn't `var i` also be local to `someMethod()`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer `let` gives you the privilege to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement of expression unlike `var`.

`var` is rather a keyword which defines a variable globally regardless of block scope

Comment: That's not quite correct. Inside a function `var` is scoped to that function.

Comment: `var` keyword defines a variable globally _regardless of block scope._

Comment: But it doesn't define it *globally* when used inside a function. In the example you have, it makes no difference whether you use `let` or `var` for `i` because the second one is defined inside the function `someMethod`. It will be a distinct variable unrelated to the `i` outside the function. Nothing changes if you use `var` instead of `let` in your example.